# Extracting NDVI Time series at specific points to CSV Table

Tags: google-earth-engine

I have a datafile of approx. 800 000 locations, from 2015-2023. I have included a subset as a sample here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RtHQUeOcP6Ta-1viGxh6fIQMomURs7UY/view?usp=sharing

I am trying to export the NDVI value (to the closest date the point was taken) for each point as a .csv from GEE. I have the code below which works to extract the NDVI over a time series for each point.

From here my plan is to filter down to just keep the entry for the lat/long on the date of interest (or closest to the date I have in my dataframe).

The code below works to get the NDVI values for all dates at each point:

```
var filtered = modis
  .filter(ee.Filter.date('2021-01-01', '2022-01-01'))


var modisNDVI = filtered.select('NDVI')
print(modisNDVI)
var scaledNDVI = modisNDVI.map(function(image){
  return image.multiply(0.0001)
  .copyProperties(image,['system:time_start','system:time_end']);
});


var triplets = scaledNDVI.map(function(image) {
  var withStats = image.reduceRegions({
  collection: farms,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean().setOutputs(['ndvi']),
  scale: 250
  }).map(function(feature) {
    return feature.set('imageId', image.id())
  })
  return withStats
}).flatten()
print(triplets.first())
```

From here, I try to convert to a table using the following code:

```
var format = function(table, rowId, colId) {
  var rows = table.distinct(rowId); 
  var joined = ee.Join.saveAll('matches').apply({
    primary: rows, 
    secondary: table, 
    condition: ee.Filter.equals({
      leftField: rowId, 
      rightField: rowId
    })
  });
         
  return joined.map(function(row) {
      var values = ee.List(row.get('matches'))
        .map(function(feature) {
          feature = ee.Feature(feature);
          var ndvi = ee.List([feature.get('ndvi'), -9999])
            .reduce(ee.Reducer.firstNonNull())
          return [feature.get(colId),(ndvi)];
        });
      return row.select([rowId]).set(ee.Dictionary(values.flatten()));
    });
};

var timeSeriesResults = format(triplets, 'farm_id', 'imageId');
print(timeSeriesResults.first())
```

However this second block outputs a NULL, and when I export as follows:

```
Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: timeSeriesResults,
  description: 'MODIS_NDVI_Series_trial',
  folder: 'earthengine',
  fileNamePrefix: 'modis_ndvi_series_trial',
  fileFormat: 'CSV'})
```

It gives me a blank .csv file, and I cannot figure out where I went wrong.

Alternatively, do you have suggestions on other ways I can extract the NDVI value at a point for a specific date over a wide range of dates and for many points?

Comment: Can you upload the sample data as an Asset in GEE, set it as a public asset and then add it to the original OP? It might be easier to help that way.